# Make timedate-indicator execute thunderbird when clicking

Tags: thunderbird

This might be a duplicate but i have searched all internet and not find an answer!
I have been editing this file.
`sudo gedit /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.indicator.datetime.gschema.xml`
Adding these keys

```
</key>
    <key name="show-Ny händelse" type="s">
        <default>true</default>
        <summary>Show Ny händelse in the indicator</summary>
        <description>
          Shows Ny händelse from Evolution in indicator-datetime's menu.
        </description>
            </key>
    <key name="exec" type="b">
        <default>true</default>
        <summary>Opens events,Tasks,Kalender,Ny händelse in the indicator</summary>
        <description>
        Opens events,Tasks,Kalender,Ny händelse from Evolution in indicator-datetime's menu.
        </description>
            </key>
    <key name="open-events" type="b">
        <default>true</default>
        <summary>Opens events in the indicator</summary>
        <description>
        Opens events from Evolution in indicator-datetime's menu.
        </description>
             </key>
    <key name="open-tasks" type="b">
        <default>true</default>
        <summary>Opens tasks in the indicator</summary>
        <description>
        Opens tasks from Evolution in indicator-datetime's menu.
        </description>
              </key>
    <key name="open-Kalender" type="b">
        <default>true</default>
        <summary>Opens Kalender in the indicator</summary>
        <description>
        Opens Kalender from Evolution in indicator-datetime's menu.
        </description>
```

D conf

![ https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfPxk.png][1]

Comment: Could this have something to do with the choices made in *System Settings* - > *Details* - > *Default Applications*?

Comment: Have thunderbird as default application for mail/calendar .Evolution is uninstalled just using the shell .

Comment: without evolution installed Time and Date settings gray out the coming events check box under clock. If you install Evolution do you get the desired result?

Comment: Yes with evolution installed evolution opens when clicking at a date or event ,but i am using lightning as calendar and the events shows up when i am adding a new 1 (without evolution installed) .Maybe i have to do an indicator thunderbirdplugin or something to make it exec.

Comment: Thunderbird uses the evolution data server so that makes sense.

Comment: Hopefully someone else on the team can chime in  and help with this one.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2011/08/11/fiddling-with-an-eds-provider-for-lightning-calendar/

Comment: It looks like there was a project but there's been no development since 8/2011

Comment: It was his guide i followed to sync the maps . So yes that is interesting.Right now i am looking at time-date setting thinking of adding the option "calendar" thanks for replies btw!

Comment: It's interesting, I'm looking forward to seeing the solution. Perhaps further work on the code here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mconley/edscalprovider/trunk/files would provide results